# Understanding contour of integration

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

A paper described a contour as following with figure given below: From $A$ to $B$, it is an ellipse with foci $\pm 1$ and $|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}| = 2 $, from $B$ to $C$ the line $z=1+re^{i \varphi}$, $\frac{3\pi}{2} \le \varphi \le 2\pi$, from $C$ to $D$ a circle with center $z = 1$ with radius $\rho$ and from $D$ to $A$, the line $z = 1+re^{i\varphi}$, $0 \le \varphi \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

[image]

My doubt is that I don't understand how the contour is a line from $A$ to $D$ and $C$ to $D$. Also, the paper doesn't specify anything about $r$. What did the paper meant?

Edit 1: Direct snapshot from the paper:

[image]

Comment: May be the line AD and BC pass through 1, and the variable is r, $\phi\$ is fixed, and have a range above.

Comment: I have tried plotting it in desmos, the curve $\left(1+r\cos \varphi,r\sin \varphi \right)$. If $\varphi$ is fixed, then what should the range of $t$? Clearly $\rho \le r$.

Comment: r should be larger than $\rho$ and r is large enough to intersect with the ellipse

Comment: Not sure why the paper seems to suggest $z=1+re^{i\phi}$ parameterizes a line segment. If $\phi$ varies over some interval, this describes a circular arc of radius $r$. Can you possibly include a direct quote or a snapshot of the passage?

Comment: Yes, I have added it in the edit. @user170231

Comment: What is your question? Is it how to solve for the coordinates of the points A, B, C, and D?

Comment: yes, @StevenClark, I want to know the corrected contour. (A to B and C to D is fine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to know the corrected contour. (A to B and C to D is fine)

Let $D$ be the point $1+\rho_D e^{i\varphi}$. Both $\rho_D$ (distance from $z_0=1$ to $D$) and $\varphi$ are fixed.

Let $A$ be the point $1+\rho_A e^{i\varphi}$. $\rho_A$ (distance from $z_0$ to $A$) is also fixed.

Now parameterize the directed line segment $\overline{DA}$ by a real variable $r$ with the function

$$z(r) = 1 + re^{i\varphi}$$

where $r\in[\rho_D,\rho_A]$.

I believe what the author is trying to communicate is that $\varphi$ is indeed fixed, but that it's chosen from the interval $\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$ so that the point $D$ lies anywhere up and to the right of $z_0$.

The line segment $\overline{BC}$ can be parameterized in the same way, just fix a different $\varphi\in\left[\frac{3\pi}2,2\pi\right]$. This ensures that $B$ lies down and to the right of $z_0$. For the sake of symmetry, for whatever $\varphi$ you select for $\overline{DA}$, pick $2\pi-\varphi$ for $\overline{BC}$.

---

Addressing a comment:

> Why is the point $A$ (as defined) on the ellipse? The equation of ellipse is $\left|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}\right|=R$

That's how we've defined $A$, a point $\rho_A$ units away from $z_0$ along a ray $\varphi$. Although $\rho_A$ is constant, its exact value depends on the constraint imposed by the ellipse equation.

Given $\varphi$, one would then have to solve

$$\left|1 + \rho_A e^{i\varphi} + \sqrt{\left(1+\rho_A e^{i\varphi}\right)^2-1}\right| = R$$

for $\rho_A$ to determine the exact coordinates of $A$.

As an example, suppose we choose $\varphi=0$. Then $A:=1+\rho_A$ would lie on the real axis, and using the constraint enforced by the ellipse we find

$$\left|1 + \rho_A + \sqrt{\left(1+\rho_A\right)^2-1}\right| = R \implies \rho_A = \frac{(R-1)^2}{2R}$$

Any other choice of $\varphi\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right]$ would make solving for $\rho_A$ quite a bit more complicated, but we can still do so systematically.

As another example, suppose we pick $\varphi=\frac\pi4$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\left|1 + \rho_A e^{i\pi/4} + \sqrt{\left(1+\rho_A e^{i\pi/4}\right)^2-1}\right| &= R \\
\left|1 + \frac{\rho_A}{\sqrt2} + i \frac{\rho_A}{\sqrt2} + \sqrt{\sqrt2\,\rho_A + i\left(\sqrt2\,\rho_A + \rho_A^2\right)}\right| &= R
\end{align*}$$

As $\rho_A>0$, so we have

$$\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x+iy} &= e^{\tfrac12 \log(x+iy)} \\
&= e^{\tfrac12 \ln|x+iy| + i\tfrac12 \arg(x+iy)} \\
&= \sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2} \, e^{i\tfrac12 \tan^{-1}\left(\tfrac yx\right)} \\
&= \sqrt[4]{x^2+y^2} \, \left(\cos\left(\frac12 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac yx\right)\right) + i \sin \left(\frac12 \tan^{-1}\left(\frac yx\right)\right)\right) \\
&= \sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}2} + i \frac{y}{\sqrt{2x+2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}
\end{align*}$$

where $x=\sqrt2\,\rho_A$ and $y=x+\frac{x^2}2=\sqrt2\,\rho_A+\rho_A^2$ (both positive) denote the real and imaginary parts of the initial radicand. In terms of $x$, our equation is

$$\left|1 + \frac x2 + i \frac x2 + \sqrt{x + i\left(x + \frac{x^2}2\right)}\right| = R$$

and the complex square root can be expanded to

$$\left|1 + \frac x2 + i \frac x2 + \sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+\left(x+\frac{x^2}2\right)^2}}2} + i \frac{x+\frac{x^2}2}{\sqrt{2x+2\sqrt{x^2+\left(x+\frac{x^2}2\right)^2}}}\right| = R$$

Now take the modulus and solve for $x$... I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader, as I think this is a sufficiently convincing demonstration of just how complicated the task can get.

---

To the plot I've added a ray indicating the choice of $\varphi$ relative to $z_0$. The smaller circle has radius $\rho_D$ and the larger one has radius $\rho_A$.

[image]

Comment: why is the point A (as defined) on the ellipse ? The equation of ellipse is $|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}| = R$

Comment: @Sam I've added some more details to my answer

Comment: To make my problem more understandable, I initially chose the equation of ellipse to be $|z+\sqrt{z^2-1}| = 2$. In the paper (see edit 1),  the right side is indeed $R$. But I am fine if you take the right side as $2$. Is it possible to simply for $R$ you have choosen when $\varphi = \frac{\pi}{4}$ instead of $0$ ?

Comment: @Sam I've updated my answer again. Short answer: yes

Comment: Thank you so much! @user170231